# the requested exception policy could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have trouble finding out the reason and fix this problem. I get this error message when I try to run my program (console application)

```
the requested exception policy 'BL Exceptions' could not be found
```

The only link i could find on internet related to this error is [this](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/751d2ca6-9fde-4979-a323-2a9c593cc9cc/enterprise-library-exception-handling)

But this post doesn't have good answer either. Please help

Comment: Are you actually using Enterprise Library or ASP like the person in the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mainly arise when migrating from lower version.
Modify your web.config to add the **legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy**.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
       <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="true" />
   </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

Once you made the configuration changes, You will get the actual exception.